# RQR for hurdle model in R

Tags: r, count, qqplot

I am struggling with calculating RQR (Randomized Quantile Residuals) for a hurdle (Negative Binomial) model in R, especially one created with the hurdle function.

I just found one source (thesis entitled Randomized Quantile Residual for Assessing Generalized Linear Mixed Models with Application to Zero-Inflated Microbiome Data) that indicates a way but it implies to separate the model into two parts and I am not really satisfied with that. It gives something like this :

```
model_count <- glmmTMB(y~ pred1+pred2, data=subset(data,SPECIES>0),ziformula=~0,family=list(family="truncated_nbinom2",link="log"))  
model_zero <- glmmTMB((y>0)~ pred1+pred2, data=data,ziformula=~0, family="binomial") 
name.y <- names(model_count$frame)[[1]]   
y    <- data[,name.y]   
m    <- model_zero$modelInfo$nobs   
mu   <- predict(model_count,newdata=data,zitype="conditional")   
size <- sigma(model_count) prob_nb <-size/(size+mu)   
pi <- 1 - predict(model_zero,newdata = data, type="response")   
u = pzmnbinom(y-1,size,prob_nb,pi)+dzmnbinom(y,size,prob_nb,pi)*runif(m)   
rqr = qnorm(u)
```

I tried also something like this (but I don't think it is the right answer) :

```
mhurdle = hurdle(y~pred1+pred2, data = data, dist = "negbin") 
y <- mhurdle$y   
m<-length(y)   
mu_count <- mhurdle$coefficients$count   
size <- mhurdle$theta   
prob_nb <- size / (mu_count + size)   
pi <- 1 - mhurdle$coefficients$zero     
u = pzmnbinom(y-1,size,prob_nb,pi)+dzmnbinom(y,size,prob_nb,pi)*runif(m)   
rqr = qnorm(u)
```

Does anyone know ? Plus, I did not found any other way to assess the goodness of fit of a hurdle model...

Thank you,

Comment: If you need help assessing the goodness of fit from a statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.